# "This is R. M'nachem." So? (שבת עה ע״ב)

Tags: rashi, maseches-shabbos

The *Bavli*, *Shabas* 75 *amud* 2, quotes from a *tosefta* as follows:

> If he wrote a single large letter, in whose space there's room to write two, he's exempt [from offering a *korban chatas*]. If he erased a large letter, in whose space there's room to write two, he's liable. *R.  M'nachem b. R. Yose* says: And this is one of the stringencies of erasing over writing.

*Rashi* comments:

> This informs us who the first *tana* [speaker in this *tosefta*] is: *R.  M'nachem b. R. Yose*.

Does *Rashi* mean he's the actual speaker, or merely that he agrees with the first speaker?

1. If the former, then (a) how does *Rashi* know? (b) How can we explain the "*R.  M'nachem b. R. Yose* says", which sounds as though the first part was not him? And (c) why does *Rashi* think we need to know he's the speaker?
2. If the latter, then (a) isn't it obvious that he agrees? What's *Rashi* telling us that we wouldn't otherwise know? And (b) why does *Rashi* think we need to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R. Ya'akov Bachrach (*Nimukei HaGRIV*, printed in the back of many editions of the Talmud) has a note on this Rashi, referencing a similarly worded discussion in [Chullin 104b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.104b.6?lang=bi):

> מתני׳ העוף עולה עם הגבינה על השולחן ואינו נאכל דברי ב"ש וב"ה אומרים לא עולה ולא נאכל א"ר יוסי זו מקולי ב"ש ומחומרי ב"ה...גמ׳ רבי יוסי היינו ת"ק...הא קמשמע לן מאן תנא קמא רבי יוסי כל האומר דבר בשם אומרו מביא גאולה לעולם שנאמר (אסתר ב, כב) ותאמר אסתר למלך בשם מרדכי‏
>
> **MISHNA: The** meat of **birds may be placed with cheese on** one **table but** may **not be eaten** together with it; this is **the statement of Beit Shammai. And Beit Hillel say:** It may **neither be placed** on one table **nor be eaten** with cheese. **Rabbi Yosei said: This is** one **of the** disputes involving **leniencies of Beit Shammai and stringencies of Beit Hillel...**
>
> **GEMARA**: The Gemara challenges: The opinion of **Rabbi Yosei is** identical to that of **the first tanna...**
>
> **[T]his** is what the mishna **teaches us: Who is the first tanna?** It is **Rabbi Yosei.** The identification is important, since **whoever reports a statement in the name of the one who said it brings redemption to the world. As it is stated** with respect to the incident of Bigthan and Teresh: **“And Esther reported it to the king in the name of Mordecai”** (Esther 2:22), and Mordecai was later rewarded for saving the king’s life, paving the way for the miraculous salvation.
>
> *(**Translation** and elucidation from sefaria.org)*

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Chullin.104b.10?lang=bi) there comments:

> והתנא שכח ולא הזכיר שמו בתחילה וחזר והזכיר שמו
>
> And the *tanna* forgot and did not mention his name at first, and then went back and mentioned his name.

Bringing this all back to the passage from Shabbat under discussion here, it appears that your first option is correct - Rashi means that R. Menachem is the author of the first part of the *beraita*.

To answer your questions:

a) Rashi knows this because of the seeming redundancy of R. Menachem's words. R. Menachem's statement that this is a stringency which applies to erasing over writing does not add anything to the first statement (just like R. Yosei's statement in the *mishnah* in Chullin does not add anything to the *tanna kamma*'s words). Something else must be going on here, and we conclude that, indeed, the sole purpose of R. Menachem's concluding statement in the *beraita* is to point out the he is in fact the author of the entire *beraita*.

b) The apparent implication that the *tanna kamma*'s words were not actually spoken by R. Menachem can be explained like Rashi says in Chullin. The first part of the *beraita* was erroneously taught anonymously. This was subsequently corrected by adding a seemingly superfluous addition in the name of R. Menachem to point out his authorship of the first part.

c) It is important for us to know this because of the principle that whoever reports a statement in the name of the one who said it brings redemption to the world (as well as explaining away the seeming redundancy of R. Menachem's statement at the end of the *beraita*).

Comment: I'm not convinced that I've presented this as clearly as possible. But it's a little involved and this is the best I could come up with at the moment. Any suggestions / improvements / edits more than welcome.